# Is this name transcribed correctly from cursive writing from 1866?

Tags: names, writing

I am trying to transcribe a list of names which were written by a child, in cursive, in 1866 (in the US).  A few of the letters are unclear to me, especially capitals.  Thanks to a few early commenter, I believe most of the names are correct.  But one is still unclear to me.  Is the thirteenth name J.F. McSone or J.F. McLone? I've left the whole list of names here for comparison.

[Source](https://digitalcommons.portlandlibrary.com/great_fire_relief/16/)

Here is my transcription so far.

> Edwin A. Colby
> Amos Colby
> G. Bailey
> Jason Fuller
> Nathan Emerson
> W. S. Simons
> W. E. Owen
> Frederic E. Pettes
> Patric McMannas
> Michael Toley
> Josiah Griffin
> James Boyd
> *J. F. McSone/McLone?
> John Fields
> Herbert F. Haines

[image]
[image]

Comment: Look closely at the signatur of ***J**osiah **G**riffin*.    Now compair, what you believe to be ***G**. F. McSone*. Everything else looks correct.

Comment: @MarkJohnson oh good catch.  I updated that one to J. F. McSone.

Comment: I see McMannas not McMarnas.  The r in Emerson and Fuller looks unlike what I see as the first n in McMannas.

Comment: And McMannus a more familiar name, too.  I'll adjust that

Comment: I see Pettes, not Peters - that really looks like a double crossed ‘t’

Comment: W S Simons, else it would be W J Jimons.

Comment: @JiminyCricket. Yes thank you

Comment: @JonCuster Pettes it is

Comment: Would anyone care to post an answer now that several commenters have chimed in? I believe I have edited the list to reflect

Comment: He writes Fredric rather than Frederic. As for adding k: There are some definite mistakes here. The kid also writes 'except' and 'cince'. So it's not unlikely that his Fredric is missing both the e and the k. As you noted, McMannas is probably also a misspelled McManus. On the other hand, people do spell their names oddly sometimes, so you can't be sure...

Comment: 3rd from bottom is J F McLone. Note that the L is the same as Lowell at the top of the page and is also the form used for the British pound symbol. The pound being libre in Latin and hence lb.

Comment: 10th name is Michael Toley, not Foley. There is no horizontal mark on the T as there is for Fuller further up. 
As for changing the spelling of names, definitely not. That is how those names were spelt back then and the boy likely had his teacher provide the names as written in the class roll. Names were pretty much set in spelling by this time, differences might happen due to illiteracy and different officials writing the same name different ways without recourse to earlier documents.

Comment: @DamionKeeling: I disagree. This is the exact style of cursive that I was taught 60 years ago, and I very clearly see the "L" in Lowell and the "S" in McSone" as distinct, and different, upper case letters. The downstroke of the "L" in Lowell is clearly drawn vertical while the equivalent stroke is clearly differently oriented in the "S" of McSone. I still struggle to fully and properly curve my upper case "S", which is what I see happening here.

Comment: I edited the question to reflect the only disagreement, mcsone/mclone

Comment: @PieterGeerkens McLone is an actual surname, McSone isn't as far as I'm aware. McLone is a variant of McLane, Maclean etc. I agree with what you say about the shape of the stroke but the capital in McSone/McLone doesn't look like the S in Simons which is further up the list. The loop at the bottom looks like it's meant to be a horizontal mark such as  you'd find in L.

Answer (score 2):

The script used by the writer is mostly a form of [Spencerian script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spencerian_script), with some capital letters slightly altered. If you look at Plate 2 (p. 73 of the scan) of [this textbook](https://archive.org/details/NewSpencerianCompendium), you will find all the letters used, albeit not in alphabetical order, but by form elements used in the letters.

Lesson XIII on page 30ff. (p.56 of the scan) contains detailed instructions on how to write what are called "Capital Stem letters". Fig. 42 compares the Letters S, L, and G. After the "stem", the initial up-and-down stroke, there follows a large oval loop to the left for S, but a small loop near the bottom line for the L. Additionally, only the L connects with an uninterupted stroke to the next letter.

The disputed name is **J. F. McLone**, not McSone.

For differences to the textbook, the writer tends to interchange curls to the left and long upstrokes for the initial movement. The B in "Bailey" is written as two strokes, the first beginning at the bottom, but as one stroke beginning at the top in "Boyd". Contrary to the taught form, the C in "Colby" begins at the bottom. Thus the L on "Lowell" begining at the top, but at the bottom in "McLone" is explainable. If you look at the S in "Simons", if you imagined a long upstroke being used instead of the upper curl, the difference to a L would still be pronounced in the way the stroke ends, with the large loop to the left.

BTW, I am in the middle of developing a script font based on this textbook. McLone (left) and McSone (right) in the current version would look like this (superscript is not implemented at this point):

[image]

Comment: I would absolutely LOVE to see what your font would print for J. F. McSone, to compare!

Comment: Here you are. You even get the benefit to see the shaded version, which I just started to test.